# Open a popup menu on another screen, on MacOS

Tags: macos, popup, screen, popupmenu

Working on **MacOS**, I need to open a popup menu from my window, but to be able to open the popup in another screen (than the window).
We are now using *performClickWithFrame* to open the popup, but it seems that if the popup location and the window view are in different screens, the menu does not open at all.
I need to find a solution for opening a popup menu from a window, when those are in different screens.
Thanks!